# Google Play Console API get release status

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-console

I try to create automatization for android apps releases.

1. Get app status
2. Publish if the status is ready to publish and approved by the release manager.

And I could not find a way to get from Google console API a release status. (ready to publish, on review, ect...).

[image]

Does anyone have solutions for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is notn available on Google Play API, you can check it here:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest

On the other hand, you could invest time on "scraping process" to fetch this kind of info directly from Google Play Console(selenium could be a good point to start).